# Upload generated PNG to amazon S3 from node on lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm downloading 2 png images from their respective URLs then using [pixelmatch](https://github.com/mapbox/pixelmatch) to compare them and generate a 3rd image.

I'm then trying to upload the third image to an S3 bucket but I'm struggling. Code follows.

`promise1` and `promise2` are the two calls to get `png1` and `png2` respectively. The `dimensions1` array used below is created in `promise1`. `PNG` is the [pngjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs) package.

```
const promArr = [promise1, promise2];

Promise.all(promArr).then(() => {
  const diff = new PNG({ width: dimensions1[0], height: dimensions1[1] });
  const pix = pixelmatch(png1.data, png2.data, diff.data, dimensions1[0], dimensions1[1], { threshold: 0.1 });
  const size = dimensions1[0] * dimensions1[1];
  diff.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`/tmp/${targetHash}.png`));
  const percentage = ((pix / size) * 100);

  const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(`/tmp/${targetHash}.png`);

  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  s3.putObject({
    ACL: 'public-read',
    Key: targetFilename,
    Body: fileBuffer,
    Bucket: targetBucket,
    ContentType: 'image/png',
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.warn(err);
      cb(err);
    } else {
      cb(null, {
        percentage,
        hash: `${targetFilename}`,
        key: `${targetFilename}`,
        bucket: targetBucket,
        url: `${event.stageVariables.endpoint}${targetFilename}`,
      });
    }
    return;
  });
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.warn(`error: ${err}`);
  cb(err);
});
```

This returns a URL to the image which Preview on mac reports to be empty. This suggests to me that I have an async issue.

I have also tried passing `diff.pack()` as the body and got the error: `Cannot determine length of [object Object]`. I found a discussion of this error [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/94).

I feel really close to a solution but I'm not quite getting there. Can anyone help? Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the permissions granted on the S3 bucket? Lambda function's associated IAM role should have write access granted to be able to write the bucket. See [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html#lambda-intro-execution-role).

Comment: @olli thanks for your comment! I'm using serverless to setup the IAM rules. Here's part of my yml:

`iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:ListBucket"
        - "s3:Put*"
        - "s3:GetObject"
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket_name}"
        - "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket_name}/*"`

Do I need something as well as put to write?

edits: I'm trying to get the formatting to behave but can't crack it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See solution below. It was an async issue. Took notes from [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/1645).
Once the pipe to create the temporary file has finished the s3 stuff kicks off. NB the use of createReadStream which is mentioned [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/94).

```
const promArr = [promise1, promise2];

Promise.all(promArr).then(() => {
  const diff = new PNG({ width: dimensions1[0], height: dimensions1[1] });
  const pix = pixelmatch(png1.data, png2.data, diff.data, dimensions1[0], dimensions1[1], { threshold: 0.1 });
  const size = dimensions1[0] * dimensions1[1];
  const percentage = ((pix / size) * 100);

  diff.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`/tmp/${targetHash}.png`).on('finish', () => {
  const fileBuffer = fs.createReadStream(`/tmp/${targetHash}.png`);

    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    s3.putObject({
      ACL: 'public-read',
      Key: targetFilename,
      Body: fileBuffer,
      Bucket: targetBucket,
      ContentType: 'image/png',
    }, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        cb(err);
      } else {
        cb(null, {
          percentage,
          hash: `${targetFilename}`,
          key: `${targetFilename}`,
          bucket: targetBucket,
          url: `${event.stageVariables.endpoint}${targetFilename}`,
        });
      }
      return;
    });
  }));
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.warn(`error: ${err}`);
  cb(err);
});
```

I'm not completely happy with writing to tmp then reading back out again but it seems to be the easiest way of dealing with aws-sdk limitations for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the stream to a buffer as mentioned in [this article](https://transang.me/modern-fetch-and-how-to-get-buffer-output-from-aws-sdk-v3-getobjectcommand/).

If you are using `node >= 17.5.0`:

```js
const streamToBuffer = (stream) => Buffer.concat(await stream.toArray());
```

If you are using `node < 17.5.0`:

```js
const streamToBuffer = (stream) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    stream.on("data", (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
    stream.once("end", () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
    stream.once("error", reject);
  });
```

And then implement it in your code:

```js
const width = dimensions1[0];
const height = dimensions1[1];

const diff = new PNG({ width, height });

pixelmatch(
  png1.data,
  png2.data,
  diff.data,
  width,
  height,
  { threshold: 0.1 }
);

const diffBuffer = await streamToBuffer(diff.pack());

await s3Client
  .send(
    new PutObjectCommand({
      Bucket: /* Bucket */,
      Key: /* Key */,
      Body: diffBuffer,
      ContentType: "image/png",
    })
  )
```